# A simple program using branching to guess the answer

Tags: beginner, ruby, number-guessing-game

As a rookie to programming, i'm really excited about finishing my first program.

But I know I only learn by making mistakes and through constructive criticism.

I'm open to any feedback regarding my use of branching, and any way to "clean up" my code.

```
puts 'Hi! Pick a number between 0 and 10'
number = gets.chomp
puts 'Got it; your number is ' + number.to_s + ', right?'
check1 = gets.chomp

if
  check1 == 'yes'
  puts 'awesome. now double your number. What\'s your new number?'
else
  puts 'Oops. Either: A. I oopsie-daisied up or B. you\'re lying.'
end

number_doubled = gets.chomp
if
  number_doubled.to_i == number.to_i * 2
  puts 'cool. Now add 6. What\'s the new number?'
else
  puts 'Oopsie-daisies'
end

number_plus_6 = gets.chomp
if
  number_plus_6.to_i == number.to_i * 2 + 6
  puts 'cool; Now divide your new answer by 2; What\'s your new number?'
else
  puts 'Oopsie-daisies'
end

number_halved = gets.chomp
if
  number_halved.to_i == number_plus_6.to_i / 2
  puts 'cool. Now, if you subtract the number you originally picked, ' + number + ', you\'re answer will be 3. Is it?'
else
  puts 'Oopsie-daisies'
end

check2 = gets.chomp
if
  check2 == 'yes'
  puts 'See? I told you i was a smarty!!'
else
  puts 'hmm, i think you\'re bad at math'
end
```

Comment: I think it is a mistake of one sort or another to add expletives to the code. Seems a bit gratuitous.

Comment: Fair enough. But if the only criticism is my poor choice of gratuitous language, than I think you're talking more about your advanced skill in etiquette and less about the code. Which is a level of coding I hope to achieve, so thanks for looking! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general this is fine. The only things I'd point out are stylistic really.

1. In Ruby, many people would prefer double-quoted strings, which allow you to: `Got it; your number is #{number}, right?`. Note that this also relies on an implicit `#to_s` on `number`. It also allows single quotes to be used without escaping.
2. Look out for variable naming. Naming things correctly is notoriously hard, even after years of experience, and `number` is a bit generic.
3. I would definitely put the `if` conditional on the same line as the `if`. If the expression is too long or a bit difficult to instinctively understand, assign its value to a variable with a meaningful name (e.g. `correctly_added_six = number_plus_6.to_i == number.to_i * 2 + 6`) so your condition is more easily understood (e.g. `if correctly_added_six`)

Good start, though!

Comment: Thanks for the positive feedback! I think I just learned about idea #3, so it makes a little more sense what you're saying.